# Ruby on Rails - can't bundle update ffi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, ffi

I need to mention ffi of version 1.0.9 (it is already mentioned in my Gemfile). The system suggested me to make "bundle update ffi", so I did it:

```
$ bundle update ffi
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
You have requested:
  ffi = 1.0.9

The bundle currently has ffi locked at 1.1.5.
Try running `bundle update ffi`
```

How to break this circularity?

P.S. I have ffi 1.0.9 already installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete `Gemfile.lock` and bundle install again.

Note: make sure your `Gemfile` does not specify a specific version.

Comment: I NEED specific ffi version, So, I'll make sure that it DOES specify specific version.

Comment: well I think it goes without saying that you don't want to specify version `x` when you really want version `y`

Comment: I did almost as you said: deleted Gemfile.lock and issued a "bundle install" command, but fixed ffi to v.1.0.9 especially for Windows because latest versions of ffi do not install themselves in Windows. It did the work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Gemfile.lock file and also make sure that your Gemfile does not have any version hard-coded (i.e. specified) for ffi then `bundle` which will create a new Gemfile.lock upon success.

Comment: Thank you. I did almost as you described (see other answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do a `bundle update` to update `Gemfile.lock`.

`ffi` is typically a dependency used by other gems, for gems like that `bundle update ffi` is usually insufficient as the versions of the dependent gems have to be rechecked/updated as well.